# TYPO3 9.5 error handling on images / resources

Tags: nginx, typo3, typo3-9.x

I successfully set up a 404 error handler in the site config:

```
errorCode: '404'
errorHandler: Page
errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=8'
```

On a page with elements of content type `text / image` following happens:
When an image is not found, it tries to include the page (width and height in frontend / image tag are set with 1080x1620px) and takes a lot of space.

Before upgrade (TYPO3 8.7) it just showed the default nginx 404 page with the backend defined width and height (imageheight 130)

How could I fix that?

EDIT: That only appears when an image is really not found. The Image-Processing works well.

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible that your images are not found?
TYPO3 normally does not generate an `img` tag if the image can not be accessed.
What HTML is generated? and where is the intended image?

I guess you have relative paths for the images, which are based on the web root path, but you use speaking urls which build pseudo folders making the relative path incorrect.

Try to use full paths:

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

Comment: This is the generated HTML: https://pastebin.com/xy1r0ryg

The absRefPrefix was already set.

Comment: You're mixing Https and http. Some browsers don't l like this. Can you request the image like given in the html from the server without error?

Comment: sorry, seems to be like just a edit fail from myself. Real Document all is https.

Comment: what about the immediate call of the image? if you use the url of the image in the html and put it in the address of the browser, what do you get in return? has the rewrite handling changed?

Comment: The image really does not exist. Only this - other images are displayed normally and are generated (seems like that wasn´t clear in my question, will edit it)

Comment: it's strange that you get a server internal reference at all, as TYPO3 usually generates references only for resources which are available. if a resource is deleted all usage of this resource should be removed. other behaviour I would consider a bug and [post a bug report](https://forge.typo3.org).